# Showing English numbers with XePersian and Minted

Tags: xetex, minted, bidi, xepersian, pygments

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{colorful}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{B Nazanin}

\definecolor{mintedbackground}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}


\newmintedfile[pythoncode]{python}{
fontfamily=tt,
bgcolor=mintedbackground,
linenos=true,
numberblanklines=true,
numbersep=5pt,
gobble=0,
frame=leftline,
framerule=0.4pt,
framesep=2mm,
funcnamehighlighting=true,
tabsize=4,
obeytabs=false,
mathescape=false,
samepage=false, %with this setting you can force the list to appear on the same page
showspaces=false,
showtabs =false,
texcl=false,
breaklines=true
}


\begin{document}


    \begin{latin}
    \pythoncode{P.py}
    222
    \end{latin}
\end{document}
```

The numbers on the left of the Python code are in Persian.  How can I change them to be in English?
(But the 222 is in English)

[image: Output of the above code]
A also have tried moving `\newmintedfile[pythoncode]{pthon}` into latin environment which did not fix the problem.

Comment: By "English" numerals, would you be referring to *arabic* numerals, i.e., 0, 1, 2, 3, ...? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding

```
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\lr{\upshape\tiny\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}
```

to your document preamble.